# Pagination in amplify nuxt project

Tags: nuxt.js, aws-amplify

I am working on amplify nuxt project and I have an issue about pagination.
I already implemented the pagination using nextToken and it is working well now. But the requirement is making the page url like /posts/page/2, /posts/page/3, etc.
When reloading the page on these kinds of url, how to get the nextToken?

Thanks